# Python - Iterating over contents of BeautifulSoup element very slow

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, html, beautifulsoup

I have a large HTML document where everything is inside a main div, structured like this:

```
<div class="main">
    \\block 1
    <div class="header"><span>content1a</span><span>content1b</span></div>
    <p>content1c</p>

    \\block 2
    <div class="header"><span>content2a</span><span>content2b</span></div>
    <p>content2c</p>

    ...
</div>
```

As you can see the contents of the header divs are related to the paragraphs, so my Python code separates these tag blocks into lists of a list so I can take out their contents later:

```
main_div = soup.find("div", class_="main")
headers = main_div.find_all("div", class_="header")

all_blocks = []
current_block = []

for tag in main_div.contents:
    if tag in headers:
        all_blocks.append(current_block)
        current_block = [tag]
    else:
        current_block.append(tag)

all_blocks.append(current_block)  # append final block
all_blocks = all_blocks[1:]  # take off first empty list
```

Problem is this seems to take forever on a ~12MB HTML file I'm feeding it (less than 1% done after 1h, while parsing the file with bs4 only took 25s).
Is there something really inefficient in my code or is this going to be slow anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you have the following:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">a</div>
    <p>b</p>

    <div class="header">c</div>
    <p>d</p>
</div>
```

And you want to extract a list of the headers grouped with the content:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

The slow part of your code is most certainly the `if tag in headers`. If header is a list of 10k elements, then for each element in `.main` you are searching through potentially 10k elements. This is horribly inefficient. If `headers` was a set, this would be more efficient, but there's no need for it to be (or for you to check `if tag in headers`).

```
def get_header_content_pairs(doc):
    main = doc.find("div", class_="main")
    headers = main.find_all("div", class_="header")

    for header in headers:
        yield (header, list(get_content(header.nextSibling)))

def get_content(element):
    while element.name == 'p':
        yield element
        element = element.nextSibling
```

Haven't tested this, but the gist is instead of doing all that work, you take advantage of the fact that each BS element knows about its `nextSibling`. You find all of the `.header`s. For each of them, you continue checking `nextSibling` until you find something that isn't a `<p>`. You aggregate these and return them with their header.

Comment: "If headers was a set [...] there's no need for it", if headers contains 10k elements, I'm pretty sure it would make a huge difference.

Comment: @IEatBagels: I understand the "no need for it" part as there is no need to make it a `set`, because the whole structure of the code can be refactored to something even better.

Comment: @IEatBagels Yeah that was just some sloppy phrasing. The "perhaps" was to suggest that you could do this, but there is really no need for checking `headers` like this at all. I'll revise

Comment: I think the OP also needs to get content in the <span> elements? Presumably you could just add this to the while condition in get_content, but I'm wondering if there's a robust way to get all content up to the next header?

Comment: @Cain Yes I omitted that detail, because it wasn't crucial to the performance issues. That would actually be in the yield, it would be like `yield (extract_header_spans(header), list(get_content(header.nextSibling))))`. As for robust, I don't know how you quantify that but `nextSibling` is a very common dom traversal technique.

Comment: Thank you! I actually looked into using `.nextSibling` but I didn't really know how I would use it properly. I didn't think about the issue of checking whether something is in a huge list (it's actually tens of thousands of elements). I also need to look into the usage of `yield`.

Answer (score 5):

Like @BaileyParker pointed out quickly, using a `set` might also be a solution to improve your code. Although I didn't test to see if this approach or his might be the fastest, I want to explain a little bit why switching `headers` from an array to a set might make a great improvement without much code modification.

Each time you use the `in` operator on an array, a range of things could happen : The element could be at the first position, which would be nice, or it could be the last, which would be long. For the sake of the example, let's say the element is always at the middle (that makes an okay mean).

So, if your `headers` element has 1000 elements, then we could assume that every time you call `in` , you go through 500 elements to find the good one.

This is because the array isn't very good at the `contains` operation. It's strong to `Add/Remove/Get` at a specific index though, but it doesn't really fit our use case. For the `Contains` operator, the array operates in O(n) time complexity.

The set, however, is very good at `Contains`, because chances are you don't need to iterate through anything. When you add an element to the set, its hash is computed and then used as a key for an underlying array (it's a little more complicated than that but the idea's there), meaning you can always access a specific elements in one shot.

I think you should try converting your `headers` array into a `set`. To do so, all you need to do is change :

```
headers = main.find_all("div", class_="header")
```

to

```
headers = set(main.find_all("div", class_="header"))
```

You might be thinking : "Okay but this operation is going to take long". It's not wrong, but it'll still be much faster than using the array every time you want to use the `in` operator.

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation of why it's problematic!

Comment: And simply doing this made it totally usable (like 100x faster), wow

Comment: @matyas I'm glad to hear that :)